# When the page refreshes, I want my settings to stay the same

Tags: jquery, html

Everybody hi, I have a setting box. And I click on the buttons in this box and am making changes as sidebard css. However, when the page is refreshed, changes made in the setting box return to the initial state. I want these settings to remain the same when the page is refreshed. I hope I'm sufficiently explanatory. Would you please examine the JQuery code below? Thank you everybody.

```
$(".option-box a.one-part").click(function(){ 
    $(".sidebar-element").removeClass("sidebar-element-multi-part");    
    $(".sidebar-element").addClass("sidebar-element-one-part"); 
    $(".sidebar").addClass("sidebar-one-part"); 

    return false
});     

$(".option-box a.multi-part").click(function(){ 
    $(".sidebar-element").removeClass("sidebar-element-one-part"); 
    $(".sidebar").removeClass("sidebar-one-part"); 
    $(".sidebar-element").addClass("sidebar-element-multi-part");   
    return false
});
```

**My Option Box Html Codes**`

```
        <!-- Option Box -->
    <div class="option-box">
        <a href="#" class="option-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

            <div class="option-box-title"><h3>SİDEBAR AYARLAR</h3></div><div class="clear"></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="one-part" href="#">Tek Parça</a></li>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <li><a class="multi-part" href="#">Çoklu Parça</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- #Option Box -->
```

**My Sidebar Html Codes**

```
            <!-- SideBar -->
        <div class="sidebar sidebar-one-part">

            <!-- Sidebar Redea Banner -->
            <div class="sidebar-element">
                <div class="banner-one">
                    <h2><i class="fa fa-window-maximize" aria-hidden="true"></i> Reklam Alanı</h2>

                    <div class="sidebar-redea-300x250">
                        <h3>Reklam Alanı</h3>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>              
            <!-- #Sidebar Redea Banner -->
```

Comment: You could use cookies, or local storage.

Comment: I wanted to ask here because there is no information in this regard. Can you help me?

Comment: You need to *store* the data somewhere.  Local storage seems like a viable and simple option.  Look for examples on how to use local storage in JavaScript.  Basically when your page loads you would check for the existence of saved values.  If they're there, use them.  If not, use your defaults.  Then whenever in your logic is appropriate, you would save the current values to local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use local storage. A good tutorial is available on W3 School ([HTML5 Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)).

It works like this (a quick example).

```
// Store 
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");

// Retrieve 
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me information, how can I adapt this rationale to my own codes?

Comment: I edited the post and added the html codes, thank you for your interest.